# Running code based on users preference

Tags: r

Because I am new in R I have some static code which I would like to make it to interact with user.

I have a manual use to use url in this format:

```
url <- c("http://www.google.com/", "http://www.anothersite.com", "http://www.yahoo.com")
```

I would like to ask the user to give me a txt with urls and parse them with the appopriate `""` and `,` and insert them to the url variable.

Also in give a solution menu like this:

```
1 - csv
2 - txt
3 - excel
```

and if the user type i.e. 1 give to the file variable the value 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple function called `readFile()` which prompts the R user for a filename.  It then attempts to read the contents of the file using `read.csv()` and returns a vector with each entry corresponding to one line from the file.

```
readFile <- function() {
    filename <- readline(prompt="Enter an filename: ")
    input <- read.csv(file=filename, header=FALSE, sep=",")
    return(input)
}
```

I created a local file called `urls.txt` with the following contents:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.bing.com
```

Here is how you can call it:

```
> url <- readFile()
Enter an filename: C:\urls.txt

> url
                     V1
1 http://www.google.com
2 http://www.yahoo.com
3 http://www.bing.com
```

As for Excel files, parsing them into R is non-trivial and would require a special package.  Just using `read.csv()` won't work out of the box for them, because they are binaries, not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think `readline` is what you need. For example:

```
> result <- readline(prompt="1 foo\n2 bar\n")
1 foo
2 bar
# Enter 2
> result
[1] "2"
```

You can learn more on readline with the R help system by typing `?readline`.

Comment: @Pascal No, if you type "2" then `result` contains "2"